# How to encrypt password or sensitive data in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I want to create rds instance and entire required infrastructure for its in aws. I couldn't understand the security part of terraform. I want to encrypt the sensitive data in .tfstate at least. e.g: password/username for rds instance etc. What will be best way to store sensitive data for .tfstate? If not supported then please suggest other ways to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AWS provider as sample.

Recommend to save the .tfstate file to s3 bucket and set the policy on it that only nominates roles have the permission to access this bucket and the related kms key.

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.10"

  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "<global_unique_bucket_name>"
    key     = "development/vpc.tfstate"
    region  = "ap-southeast-2"
    kms_key_id = "alias/terraform"
    encrypt = true
  }
}
```

Always enable `version control` on that s3 bucket.